# How can I change the color of gedit's spell checking underline?

Tags: gedit, colors, spell-checking

I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.10 today, and in its version of gedit (3.10.4), the spell-checking plugin highlights misspelled words in light grey. Is there a way to change it back to red? I poked around the Color Scheme Editor and couldn't find a corresponding style.

Comment: Please try editing  /usr/lib/gedit/plugins/terminal.py in the terminal. In that change fg and bg.

Comment: After more research, I suspect I need to custom build gedit. I downloaded the source with 'apt-get source' and started poking around. The spellcheck plugin uses PANGO_UNDERLINE_ERROR to mark misspelled words, but doesn't use [pango_attr_underline_color_new](https://developer.gnome.org/pango/stable/pango-Text-Attributes.html#pango-attr-underline-color-new) to change the color of the underline, so the foreground color is used (black, which is light gray when thin). Something must've changed between versions of Pango...I figured I'd add the line myself, but even the stock version won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer to the problem, but a quick trick:

change the set of colors used by gedit in the preferences.
In some sets the light gray is clearly visible.